# android - number formatting based on locale

Tags: locale, number-formatting

being a newbie to android I have some code combined as below in the aim of displaying a specific number 12345.66 differently according to the custom locale. However it just crashed my test application and I couldn't figure out why...Appreciate some help here. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
//get current locale and display number
Configuration sysConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
Locale curLocale = sysConfig.locale;
String aNumber = "12345.66";
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(curLocale);
aNumber = nf.format(aNumber);
numberText.setText(R.string.numberText + aNumber);
```

Layout.xml:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:id="@+id/nbumberText"
/>
```

Comment: Error msg shows: sorry, the app has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. Then i have to force close the app.

Comment: anyone have a solution to get the raw number back from formatted number string?

Answer (score 18):

According to Android/Java documentation, you can use **java.text.NumberFormat**:

NumberFormat.getInstance().format(myNumber);

This will use the current user's locale.

More information on http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

This statement is very suspicious:

```
numberText.setText(R.string.numberText + aNumber);
```

What do you mean by that?  Is it a typo?

To display the formatted number, probably you should only need:

```
numberText.setText(aNumber);
```

By the way, I guess you have not used the debugger.  A serious developer definitely need that.

Comment: Thank you, tried "numberText.setText(aNumber);" but still not working. So basically i think there is something wrong with the numberformat and parsing, but i can't tell what's wrong, and i couldn't get a clue from the debugger...

Answer (score 0):

It crashes because `NumberFormat.format()` takes in `Double` or a `Long`, but not a `String`. So:

```
aNumber = nf.format(aNumber);
```

Should be:

```
aNumber = nf.format(new Double(aNumber));
```